# How to set window title to cwd + current opened file

Tags: vimrc, neovim

Does anyone know if it's possible to change the window title for nvim to this pattern:

```
{cwd}/{current-file} - vim
```

E.g.

```
my_project_dir/README.md - vim
```

I'm using [nvim-qt](https://github.com/equalsraf/neovim-qt) with i3wm (I'm not sure if it matters for this).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the 'titlestring' option to an expression that returns statusline expandos that will be evaluated by Vim and displayed in the title. E.g. use
something like this:

```
:set title titlestring=%(%{expand(\"%:~:.:h\")}%)/%t\ -\ Vim
```

Read the help at [:h 'statusline'](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#'titlestring') and [:h 'statusline'](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#'statusline')
for the meaning of those items.

Comment: Hmmm. Interesting syntax. I don't read cuneiform, and I'm not familiar with the Rosetta Stone, but when I see something like that with no explanation it makes me say %#!@$!

Comment: @markling the explanation is given in the mentioned help sections :)